# Angular2+/Rxjs Observable constructor/ngOnInit - routing onPageChange

Tags: angular, rxjs, observable, angular2-routing

i am facing a problem with Observable and Component lifecycle.
Here a dummy stackBlitz:

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-tpytgx

I need to trigger on every pageChange some specific method on different components.

```
  ngOnInit() {
    this.actionsOnRouteChange();
  }

  actionsOnRouteChange() {
    this.router.events.subscribe(event => {
      if (!(event instanceof NavigationEnd) || typeof window === 'undefined') {
        return;
      }
      this.myService.pageChange();
    });
  }
}
```

Initially i had a code like this but i was struggling because `pageChanged$` is not unsubscribed and so was triggered also on pages where the component was not loaded at all.

```
  ngOnInit(){
    this.myService.pageChanged$
      .subscribe(() => this.myService.printOnConsole('Hello there!' + this.name))
  }
```

So i changed the code in this way.

```
  subscriptionAlive = true;

  constructor(
    private myService: MyService
  ) {
  }

  ngOnInit(){
    this.myService.pageChanged$
      .pipe(
        takeWhile(() => {
          console.log('alive', this.subscriptionAlive);
        return this.subscriptionAlive})
      )
      .subscribe(() => this.myService.printOnConsole('Hello there!' + this.name))
  }

  ngOnDestroy(){
    this.subscriptionAlive = false;
  }
```

Now that i solved the previous problem the callback of the subscribe is not fired at all and i suspect that is because the **pageChanged$** is emitted before that the component is loaded so the subscribe part is not yet initialized.
For this reason i moved the subscribe into the constructor in this way:

```
  constructor(
    private myService: MyService
  ) {
    this.myService.pageChanged$
      .pipe(
        takeWhile(() => {
          console.log('alive', this.subscriptionAlive);
        return this.subscriptionAlive})
      )
      .subscribe(() => this.myService.printOnConsole('Secret Info!'))
   }
```

Now it works like a charm but until i don't need to pass in the component from his parent with `@Input` that we know is not initialized yet in the constructor.

In the StackBlitz the **informationComponent** is the one that is working good without any data passed from `@Input` instead the **helloComponent** is the one that need to use data passed from parent component that is not working good.

I tried also `ngOnChanges` and i played also with `BehaviorSubject` without success.

What am i missing??

Thank you!

### UPDATE 1

I moved back all subscribe of every component on `ngOnInit` and i changed `Subject<boolean>()` to `BehaviorSubject<boolean>(null)` and now it's working but i have encountered another problem that i tried to reproduce on StackBlitz without success.
In my real app the component (ListMeComponent) that use a decorator`@ViewChild`seems call the emitter twice, on `ngOnInit` and then on `afterViewInit` also if the code of the subscribe is wrote only inside `afterViewInit` like in stackBlitz.

### UPDATE 2

I solved problems with `@ViewChild` decorator setting `{ static: true }` to be able to use it on `ngOnInit` and then i found that `BehaviorSubject` was firing twice, that's his normal behavior because also if emit is null it will works, cause i need `SubjectBehavior` i solved emitting value `true` and adding a pipe filter to the subscribe.

```
  private pageChanged = new BehaviorSubject<boolean>(null);
  pageChanged$ = this.pageChanged.asObservable();

  pageChange() {
    this.pageChanged.next(true);
    console.log('pageChanged emitted');
  }
```

```
    this.myService.pageChanged$
      .pipe(
        takeWhile(() => this.subscriptionAlive),
        filter(isTrue => isTrue)
      )
      .subscribe(() =>
        this.myService.printOnConsoleList(
          'List',
          this.mobileOccasions.nativeElement.offsetParent !== null
        )
      );
```

I have updated also the stackblitz.

Comment: Please share the actual StackBlitz code, not just the preview..

Comment: @MikeOne thank you for pointing it out, i changed the url and did an update to the code and the question